# How to show only on screen with certain width JS

Tags: javascript, screen, document

I am using the following code

Screen bigger 999px

```
<script>
    if ((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) >= 999) {
        // Show on screens bigger than 999px
    }
</script>
```

Screen smaller than 767px

```
<script>
    if ((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) < 767) {
        // Show on screens smaller than 767px
    }
</script>
```

Now my goal is to display somthing inbetween 970 and 768

I have tryed the following code, but this is also visible below 767px

```
<script>
    if ((window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) < 970) {
        // Show on screens from 970 till 768
    }
</script>
```

How can I set this up it will only show on screens from 970 till 768? I can't use CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

if( width >=768 && width <= 970){
    // do what you need
}
```

[logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)

Answer (score 0):

```
let width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

if( width >=768 && width <= 970){
    // Show on screens between 768 and 970 px
}
else if (width < 768){
    // Show on screens smaller than 768px

}
else if (width > 970){
    // Show on screens bigger than 970px
}
else {
   // Show other cases

}
```